# Changing encoding in the editor for Turkish character

Tags: texshop, input-encodings

I had written all my tex files with latin5 encoding in texshop on Mac. Now I want to change the encoding to utf8 because all the files I get from my colleague are encoded with uft8. However, when I change the encoding all the Turkish characters in my old latex files are being corrupted. Is there any way to have a correct encoding for Turkish characters in the old files when I change the encoding?

Edit: I think in order to be more clear it will be better to show the situation by a photo. As can be seen after changing editor encoding from its preferences from latin5 to uft8 and reopening the file it looks like in the upload photo. All the Turkish characters are corrupted.

[image]

Comment: utf-8 can handle Turkish, how are you doing the conversion, and what error do you get? Hard to help with no information in the question

Comment: If your TeX files had previously loaded `inputenc`, either delete it, to use the default UTF-8 encoding, or else replace it with `selinput` so it will work automatically in any encoding.

Comment: Another thing to check is that PDFLaTeX does not support combining accents (although LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX do), so make sure you are converting to precomposed (NFC) form.

Comment: Actually it is not about the PDFLaTeX. If I write a new file with uft8 encoding everything seems alright. Please see my editing.

Comment: did you actually convert the file from latin5 to utf-8 or simply  open the original file after telling the editor to use utf-8. save copies of the file in case things go wrong, but what happens if you open the file as latin5 is it OK?

Comment: I didn't convert the file, only changed the encoding of the editor. Actually, I don't know if there is a way to convert the file as well. After changing encoding again to latin5 from uft8 the tex file seems right.

Comment: OK so that is the issue then, you are simply seeing a latin5  file wrongly viewed as utf-8. There are lots of tools to convert files from one encoding to another I would be surprised if texshop can not "save as utf-8" but I do not have that editor (or a Mac) but someone will be able to answer, I am sure.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle. I found a solution but it's quite tedious. If I click save as the document and select encoding as uft8 then use uft8 for the editor it works. But it will take a lot of time to do the same thing for lots of files. Thanks again for your comments.